# Integer optimization problem

Tags: optimization

Suppose we are given $Av - x \ge 0$, for a given $n \times n$ matrix A and an $n\times 1$ vector $x$. Find an integer valued vector $v$ of size $n \times 1$ such that $\mathbf{1} \cdot v$ is minimized (in other words the sum of its elements is minimized)

Also, A is symmetric and invertible, if that helps.

Any idea how to attack this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its an Linear programming problem,
$$ \min 1^T v$$
$$\text{s.t } Av > x$$
There exist many method for solving Integer LP. Write the above Optimization function in standard form and you can use Simplex method.

Standard Form:
$$ -\max (-1^Tv)$$
$$\text {s.t }-Av < x $$

Comment: Thanks, it should be called "integer linear programming" to be more exact.